# Nail sticking out other side of wooden door - how do I remove the sharp end?

Tags: nails

I've hammered two nails into a wooden door and approx. 2mm (the sharp ends) are sticking out the other side.

What's the best/easiest way to take the ends off the nails?

Thanks in advance,
Stephen[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can spend 30 min ( or much more ) filing them down and who know how much time repairing the file mark on door or you could spend 10 min removing them and replacing them with an appropriate size SCREW.

Tap the point of the nail until the head of the nail is out far enough to get a pry bar or the claws of a hammer on it and pull it out (gently and protect the door from the hammer or bar with a scrap of wood).

Install a screw that has a larger diameter that the nail and is shorter. If the door is hollow you may need an anchor for the screw and if it is hollow a nail is not the appropriate fastener.

Answer (score 0):

Either grind them off with a grinder, or try to use a nail set and bend over the tip without pushing the nail back out the other side.

I suggest a grinder.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I don't have a grinder but do have a metal file - would that work?

Comment: Certainly. It'll be a little more work, and you may want to tape off around the nails to protect the surrounding surface, but with the right drive, a file will do a fine job.

Comment: Are the nails fully set on the other side? Is the head of the nail flush with the door?

Comment: Yes, the nail heads are holding in a towel hook and are flush against the hook/door...

Answer (score 0):

You can partially cut with nail nippers then grip with pliers and carefully bend back and forth a couple of times to break the nail.

Given that the nails are protruding very little, bend across the grain with a spring drive nail set punch (google or amazon or youtube to see one in action--not expensive) to bury the sharp points into the wood.

A Dremel tool with a cutting disc will work, but is slower.